# Suppressing messages in RMarkdown - not working

Tags: r-markdown

I have the below code:

```
    eng <- rgdal::readOGR(paste0("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/",
                                 "8d3a9e6e7bd445e2bdcc26cdf007eac7_4.geojson"))
    
    countries <- rgdal::readOGR(paste0("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/",
                                       "92ebeaf3caa8458ea467ec164baeefa4_0.geojson"))
    
    eng <- sf::st_as_sf(eng)
    countries <- sf::st_as_sf(countries)
    UK <- countries[-1,] 
    names(eng)[3] <- "Region"
    names(UK)[3] <- "Region"
    UK$objectid <- 10:12
    eng <- eng[-2]
    UK <- UK[c(1, 3, 9:11)]
    UK <- rbind(eng, UK)
     UK<-UK%>% arrange(Region)
    UK$Sales<-c(49, 118, 51, 27, 53, 140,76,45,51,11,55,48)
               
    
    ggplot2::ggplot(UK, ggplot2::aes(fill = Sales)) + ggplot2::geom_sf()+
      scale_fill_gradient(low='green', high='blue')+
      theme(axis.line.x.bottom = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            axis.line.y.left = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_blank())+labs(fill = "Number of car sales\n (7th October 2019\n - 26th 

    January 2020)")
```

I get this output in the final PDF:

```
## OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON
## Source: "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8d3a9e6e7bd445e2bdcc26cdf007eac7_4.geojson", layer: "Region__December_2015__Boundaries"
## with 9 features
## It has 5 fields
## OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON
## Source: "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/92ebeaf3caa8458ea467ec164baeefa4_0.geojson", layer: "Countries__December_2019__Boundaries_UK_BUC"
## with 4 features
## It has 10 fields
```

Is there any way I can stop this, I have set messages=FALSE, Warning=FALSE, Echo=FALSE, but still get the same

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved this. This seems to have worked

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide'}
````

Comment: And if you use Rstudio, when you create your chunk, to the right of the chunk inside the script editor you can click the gear icon and select on and off multiple Rchunk options for easy control